Unable to keep ID when using st_interpolate_aw, as the output object is 1 polygon short of the "to" object
I cannot recreate this problem in publicly available data, because it seems to be a data specific problem.
I have 2 sf objects, shown here by the gray (2020) and black (1970) borders. Both have been run through st_make_valid(), and st_is_valid() returns TRUE for all polygons. Dimensions are as as written here:
dim(soilshape.sf.drop) # the 2020 polygon with soil data is 693  11
dim(dist1970.sf)       # the 1970 polygon is 386   3
length(dist1970.sf$ID) # the length of the ID is obviously 386
length(unique(dist1970.sf$ID))  # also 386 -- a unique ID

I would like to run the following code, which I understand should create a new ID within the object atest1 that holds the unique polygon id ID from dist1970.sf:
atest1 = st_interpolate_aw(soilshape.sf["Zn_s"], dist1970.sf, extensive = FALSE) |>
  mutate(ID = dist1970.sf$ID)

However, it return no object, just this error:
Error in `stopifnot()`:
ℹ In argument: `ID = dist1970.sf$ID`.
Caused by error:
! `ID` must be size 385 or 1, not 386.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

I think this is due to the fact that, when I don't pipe through mutate(), the output being created doesn't have 386 polygons -- it has 385. That is, when I run this code:
atest2 = st_interpolate_aw(soilshape.sf["Zn_s"], dist1970.sf, extensive = FALSE)

I get an object atest2 with dimensions 385 x 2, not 386 x 2 as expected.
Can anyone speculate as to what is going on -- why st_interpolate_aw() is creating an object that is 1 polygon short of the number in dist1970.sf / why I am unable to use the mutate() pipe-through to bring my dist1970.sf ID with me? And how to fix it? The interpolated data is unusable at the moment since I can't match it back to the original IDs.

I found the answer! I needed to include the keep_NA = TRUE option, to keep missing values in both the data extraction and the IDs maintained. So this works now:
atest = st_interpolate_aw(soilshape.sf["Zn_s"], dist1970.sf, extensive = FALSE, keep_NA = TRUE) |>
  mutate(ID = dist1970.sf$ID)

That is, atest is the same length as dist1970.sf, and includes the ID field from dist1970.sf.
